# Оптимизация кода по поиску файлов c#

Tags: c#, search

Добрый день, у меня стоит такая задача : найти все `png` файлы в диске и переименовать их, как я сделал :

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    try
    {
        var images = Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.png");
        images.ToList().AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(100).ForAll(dd => Rename(dd));
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        foreach (string path in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            DirSearch(path);
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    } 
}
```

Собственно сам вопрос : достаточно ли он оптимизирован ? Нужно как можно быстрее обработать все png файлы, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Есть подозрение что для IO операций (чтения имен файлов) куча потоков будет скорее замедлять процесс, чем ускорять

Comment: Лучше использовать `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, и убрать распараллеливание. Возможно с SSD производительность и не пострадает, но на механике точно будет хуже. Плюс к тому не забывайте, что ОС тоже активно использует диск, и еще куча другого софта, который так или иначе установлен на целевой машине тоже может использовать диск если не постоянно, то периодически. В любом случае вы всегда можете сделать замеры скорости и выбрать лучший вариант.

Comment: @tym32167 да, скорее всего так и есть, само собой при 100 потоков память тратится больше, но и скорость возрастает, в 10 потоков быстрее обошел весь диск, чем в 100

Comment: @rdorn вместо Directory.GetFiles использовать Directory.EnumerateFiles я вас правильно понял ? Так же убрать дополнительные потоки и просто юзать форич ?

Comment: @Lolidze да, Ну и для перечисления папок есть такой же метод. Собственно суть в том, что в таком случае, вы не выгружаете весь список файлов в память. Какой-то системный кэш создается, но он создается в любом случае.

Comment: ясно, спасибо, попробую. Кстати, а можно как-то получить только файлы, которые были изменены не давно (скажем, месяц) ? или надо так же получать весь список, потом к каждому файлу получать дату изменения и потом только фильтровать ?

Comment: Вообще, возможность параллельных IO-операций сильно зависит от окружения и самих операций. Иногда это реально, и действительно увеличивает скорость, но чаще наоборот. Можно, если использовать DirectoryInfo и FileInfo соответственно

Comment: @rdorn спасибо большое