# Распараллеливать задачу до выполнения условия c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Сама суть : есть массив строк, есть метод, который принимает 1 строку и работает с ней, результат выполнения метода может быть положительным или отрицательным. Цель : Нужно в несколько потоков (с возможностью ограничения потоков) вызывать метод (посылая все новую строку из массива) пока :

1. Не закончатся в массиве строки

   ИЛИ
2. Выполняться успешно n строк. Например, в массиве 100 строк, n=10, как только метод успешно выполнился 10 раз завершаем работу.

Пока что, я смог реализовать все, кроме пункта 2

```
   CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var opt = new ParallelOptions
            {
                CancellationToken = cts.Token,
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = kolthread //кол-во максимальных потоков
            };


            Parallel.ForEach(lines, opt, a => Metod(a));//lines- массив строк
```

Можете помочь реализовать пункт 2 ?

Comment: Ведите счетчик, если счетчик больше или равен 10 - завершайте потоки.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов яб ввел, но как завершить создание новых потоков `Parallel.ForEach(lines, opt, a => Metod(a));` ?

Comment: А CancellationToken не для этого служит?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-parallel-for-or-foreach-loop

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да, спасибо большое, как раз хотел вас попросить дать пример и тут Leoinid сразу его дает )

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev спасибо большое за ссылку

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev на я на .NET и три слова не свяжу :-)

Comment: ктот из вас может оформить ответ, чтоб не казался, что вопрос не решен )) спасибо за помощь

Comment: кстати, можно еще вопрос ?  `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = kolthread` - в данном случае, `Parallel.ForEach` запустит ровно столько потоков и по завершению одного сразу запустит другой или он может запустить 2-3 потока и усе ? Просто, был у меня опыт с `AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(100).ForAll` - и вызывал метод для поиска файлов [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690845/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-c) тогда запускались 2-3 потока.

Comment: и смысла от ограничения не было

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2 Этим параметром можно ограничить сверху, но нельзя задать количество потоков, которое будет использоваться, так что, если вам не требуется ограничение сверху, то не меняйте его.

Comment: @rdorn ограничивать надо, но вопрос был в другом, есть ли смысл. в `AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(100).ForAll` , как я понял, создаст столько потоков, сколько ядер у процессора (по крайне мере для метода поиска файлов). Хотелось бы узнать ситуацию с `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Сколько потоков будет создано будет зависеть от алгоритма, который должен выполняться в потоке. Может быть по числу ядер, может и больше, если в потоке происходит асинхронное ожидание ответа удаленно сервера, например. Поэтому задать нижнюю границу невозможно. В обоих случаях поведение будет одинаково, т.к. будет использоваться пул потоков. Руками вы можете создать сколько угодно потоков, но точно также, реально работать одновременно будет столько, сколько позволяет алгоритм внутри потока.